# Why ML.NET Matrix Factorization makes no sense predictions

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

I developed a product recommender using ML.NET matrix factorization. The train data has 20000 entries and contains only pairs of product ids (no ratings), so I adapted the trainer accordingly to Microsoft documentation.

The training data only contains pairs of MAN products or WOMAN products, never mixed:

```
ProdutMan1 ProductMan2
ProductWoman1 ProductWoman2
ProductMan3 ProductMan5
ProductWoman3 ProductWoman6
```

Despite this there are recommendations of WOMAN products made from a MAN product. I don't understand this behaviour of the algorithm since, considering the training data, those two types of product never appear associated.

The options passed to the trainer are:

```
MatrixFactorizationTrainer.Options options = new MatrixFactorizationTrainer.Options();
            options.MatrixColumnIndexColumnName = "ProductIdEncoded";
            options.MatrixRowIndexColumnName = "CoPurchaseProductIdEncoded";
            options.LabelColumnName = "Label";
            options.LossFunction = MatrixFactorizationTrainer.LossFunctionType.SquareLossOneClass;
            options.Alpha = 0.01;
            options.Lambda = 0.025;
            options.NumberOfIterations = 500;
            var est = MLContext.Recommendation().Trainers.MatrixFactorization(options);
```

Comment: The usual data format for Matrix Factorization to recommend products is having 2 fields : a user ID and a product ID. Maybe you should read more examples about applications of Matrix Factorization and make sure that this algorithm suits your use case and your data.

Comment: @Y.P There are multiple examples of matrix factorization using pairs of products. It's just a matter of interpret the model in a different way, userId would be replaced by productId representing a pair of products bought together. In the end instead of having products bought by user I have products bought together with a given product.